# Shorthand for assignment if nil in Swift?

Tags: swift

```
if x == nil {
    x = y
}
```

I know the statement above can be rewritten as:

```
x = x ?? y
```

But `x ??= y` is not accepted by compiler. Is there a shorthand not to repeat `x`?

Comment: Operator ??= was rejected from Swift evolution: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.swift.evolution/7694

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Laffen’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34061557/1779477) answer is great. However, it is not exactly equivalent to `x = x ?? y` as the right hand side is always evaluated with their definition of `??=` as opposed to the standard `??` operator.

If you want to have this behavior too, `@autoclosure` is here to help:

```
infix operator ??=
func ??=<T>(left: inout T?, right: @autoclosure () -> T) {
    left = left ?? right()
}
```

Comment: works in swift 5. only evaluates the right hand side if the left hand side is `nil`. ++

Answer (score 8):

Check this out, put the following in global code space(In your Extensions.swift maybe). This creates a custom operator you can use throughout your entire project.

**Swift 2**

```
infix operator ??= {}
func ??= <T>(inout left: T?, right: T) {
    left = left ?? right
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
infix operator ??=
func ??= <T>(left: inout T?, right: T) {
    left = left ?? right
}
```

Usage:

```
var foo: String? = nil
var bar = "Bar"
foo ??= bar
print("Foo: \(bar)")
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I get an error when trying this on Swift 3. Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat' to expected argument type 'inout _?' (aka 'inout Optional<_>')

Comment: You need to define the `CGFloat` as an `Optional`, like this: `var foo: CGFloat?`

Answer (score 3):

This code works in playground:

```
var x: Int? = nil
let y = 5
x = x ?? y // x becomes 5
```

and

```
var x: Int? = 6
let y = 5
x = x ?? y // x stays 6
```

By the way here are some variants of checking for nil:

```
if x != nil {
    // classic
}

if x != .None {
    // nil in Swift is enum with value .None
}

if let _x = x {
    // if you need it's value
}
if let _ = x {
    // if you don't need it's value
}
```

UPD: code for project - copy and run it:

```
var x: Int? = nil
let y = 5
x = x ?? y
print (x)
x = 7
x = x ?? y
print (x)
```

Comment: Are you sure `x` is changed? In my case, `x` remains nil and only the result of `x ?? y` is `y`.

Comment: @yzyzsun Yes, sure. I just fixed some code and provided update. See it